# Is there a way to add users to BIM projects with all available services? Using Forge BIM 360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Our BIM 360 environment we have four available Services(Document Management, Model Coordination, Design Collaboration and Insight). But in the documentation [projects/:project_id/users/import](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/) it had only has Document Management available in the available services. Is this just a known limitation? Or is there any other way to achieve adding all services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is a known limitations. We have a wish logged against this:

ACSADMIN-530 (was HQ-3034): “API wish: adding users beyond Docs”

Not truly a workaround, but one way (in desperate need) might be to add as an admin using the other endpoints:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-POST/

you can find a list of services listed on this page:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360.project.setup.tool
the table toward the bottom.

Comment: Thank you @Mikako this gives me some options at least. Much appreciated.